# problem with notifications module

Tags: php, email, drupal, drupal-6, notifications

This problem is in drupal

I have used your notification module and have implemented in a site which has been working for the past 6 months.
It is an awesome module and has reduced my efforts in implementing it.
my implemention area was for sending notifications to groups.

For groups we have used og module and have used discussion as content type.
I have enabled settings for posting discussions on group.
To send mails to all group members have used notifications module.

It was working fine(hopefully), it suddenly stopped working.
I think i found out the reason, the data from one table was getting deleted.
The table is notification_fields.
total records where around 200000 now it is less than 15.

I think that due to this auto deletion of records the notifications are not sent.

I had also posted /searched in different sites for this kind of problem, but didn't work.

could you please tell me if it is the reason behind it. and what is to be done in the case that it doesn't delete.

Hope so i have explained enough of the problem i am currently facing.

Awaiting for your response.

Comment: You may get a better response at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/.